# C++11 Random numbers in a range and explicit likeliness

Tags: c++, c++11, random, probability

I would like to know I can generate random numbers(C++11) in a given range and have control over the likeliness of some number(s) to come up. Say I generate random numbers between 0 and 4 with number "1" 50% likely to be drawn in the set.

Answer (score 8):

If the range is [0, n) then you can use [`std::discrete_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution).

For your specific example of setting 1 to be 50% you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::discrete_distribution<> d({10, 50, 30, 10});
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << d(gen) << '\n';
    }
}
```

There are other sampling distributions you can use like [`std::piecewise_constant_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_constant_distribution) and [`std::piecewise_linear_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_linear_distribution). Along with many other different distributions in the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header.

Comment: There are literally an infinite number of other things he could do as well that would be equally correct.  There's nothing wrong with your solution, but the problem statement as given has too many degrees of freedom to have a unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [std::discrete_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution)

Answer (score 0):

There are a metric buttload of different probability distributions/models, all of which can be generated via a variety of techniques which are described in most simulation textbooks.  If you want a more specific answer to your question, you need to be more specific about the distribution you want to generate from.  You only specified the probability for one of the five possible outcomes, and there are an infinite number of potential probability assignments for the remaining four.

If you intend to generate random numbers without a decent understanding of probability theory and distribution modeling, you're begging for trouble.  I would strongly recommend going and reading chapters 4, 6, 7, and 8 of ["Simulation Modeling and Analysis" by Law](http://highered.mcgraw-hill.com/sites/0072988436/), or some similar text.